# MLE of Laplacian with linear parameters

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, linear, laplace-distribution

I'm stumped on this problem and was hoping someone could give me some guidance. I'm new to this sort of thing so it's possible that I'm leaving something out of this question or that my question isn't going to be well posed so please bear with me. Thanks in advance for any help!

If given a sample of $\Delta_{i}$, $x_{i}$ where $x_{i}$ is drawn from some Laplacian with scale and diversity linear functions of $\Delta_{i}$, i.e. $x_i\sim Laplace(\mu(\Delta_i),b(\Delta_i))$, with $\mu(\Delta)=\alpha_\mu\Delta+\beta_\mu$ and $b(\Delta)=\alpha_b\Delta+\beta_b$. What would the MLE derivations of $\alpha_\mu$, $\beta_\mu$, $\alpha_b$, and $\beta_b$ be?

I got $-LL=\sum_{x_i}\left[\frac{|x_i-\mu(\Delta_i)|}{b(\Delta_i)}+log(2b(\Delta_i))\right]$, but then I got blocked because I didn't know how to deal with the $\mu$ and $b$ terms in the summation / absolute value. When I try to differentiate this with respect to the $\mu$ I get a function of $b$, and when I try and differentiate with respect to $b$ everything remains stuck inside the summation.

---

#### Edit 1:

I found [this paper](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jam/2014/856350/) which, although I didn't understand it, seemed to suggest that there isn't a closed for solution for linear regression with laplacian residuals.

If this is the case, it lead me to wonder if there's a good approximation for a laplacian distribution that I could use that would allow me to approximate these parameters. I wasn't able to find anything on this subject, and tried playing around with it myself by approximating a laplacian with a series / mixture of gaussians, but I wasn't able to find a nice rule that defined a series which accomplished this.

So I guess some other components of my question would be: Is it possible to analytically derive a closed form solution to my original question? If so, are there any approximation techniques that could help?

Comment: Could ytou clarify your notation, which is quite non-standard? What is $\Delta_i$?

Comment: I happened to use $\Delta$ because that variable corresponded to arrival time. You can think of it as a random variable drawn from an exponential distribution if that's helpful?